# How to access mounted drive using terminal if drive contain space in name?

Tags: command-line, mount, media

Here I am having some problem that how to access any NTFS drive that I have mounted.
I want to access that drive using terminal and for that I have used

cd /media/{username}/{drive-name}
but in my case drive contains space in its name so for that I am not able to connect my drive using terminal help me for that.. please

Comment: Doesn't `cd '/media/{username}/{drive-name}'` work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Put the name in between double quotes (`"`) but you can also escape the space or use the tab to auto-complete. These will work:

```
cd /media/rinzwind/"disc world"
cd /media/rinzwind/disc\ world
```

But this will work too:

```
cd /media/rinzwind/disc{tab}
```

and the last one will add the remainer and escape the input.

Example:

```
mkdir "tmp tmp"
$ cd tmp\ tmp/
```

where I hit the tab after the 1st "t".

Comment: Great, +1 for disc world. =) ok, the answer is ok :P ^^